# After second assign TPngImageCollectionItem object TreeView still paint first assigned image(Delphi XE 7)

Tags: delphi, treeview, tpngimagelist

I use last TPngComponents "[PngComponents for Delphi 2009 - Delphi 10.2 Tokyo](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127)".
Create simple [project](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhcEbRD3rLxAgYTWSJz4ST9zR1KLAtw) to show my problem.

Why after the second assign TPngImageCollectionItem object TreeView still paint first assigned image and may be need call some refresh functions?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    pilTree: TPngImageList;
    pilNoImage: TPngImageList;
    pilAllCor: TPngImageList;
    tvCor: TTreeView;
    pilAllNotCor: TPngImageList;
    tvNoCor: TTreeView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure AddNodes(ATV: TTreeView);
var
  nFirst, nChild: TTreeNode;
begin
  nFirst := ATV.Items.AddChild(nil, '1');
  nChild := ATV.Items.AddChild(nFirst,'2');
  nChild.ImageIndex := 1;
  nChild.SelectedIndex := 1;
  nFirst.Expanded := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  iI: Integer;
  ItemAdd: TPngImageCollectionItem;
  ANode: TTreeNode;
begin
  // Steps working correct
  for iI := 0 to 1 do begin
    ItemAdd := pilAllCor.PngImages.Add;
    ItemAdd.Assign(pilTree.PngImages[iI]);
  end;
  // Steps working NOT correct
  for iI := 0 to 1 do begin
    ItemAdd := pilAllNotCor.PngImages.Add;
    ItemAdd.Assign(pilNoImage.PngImages[0]);
    ItemAdd.Assign(pilTree.PngImages[iI]);
  end;

  //Setup treeview
  tvCor.Images := pilAllCor;
  tvNoCor.Images := pilAllNotCor;
  AddNodes(tvCor);
  AddNodes(tvNoCor);
end;
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please include the minimal code to reproduce the problem in your question, not behind links to external resources (which may become invalid, and thus render your question useless for future readers)

Comment: I try add all but got message about a lot code and no explanation and not find function like hide text where I can store all file.

Comment: If your example is too large it is probably not minimal enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to add a *TPngImage* to a *TPngImageList* is using *AddPng* and not fiddling around with the collection. This will also update the underlying Windows image list responsible for the actual display of the image.

The correct code should look like:

```
  for iI := 0 to 1 do begin
    pilAllCor.AddPng(pilTree.PngImages[iI].PngImage);
  end;
```

If you want to change an existing item you should assign the *PngImage* property of the collection item:

```
    pilAllCor.PngImages[iI].PngImage := pilTree.PngImages[iI].PngImage;
```

Comment: Thank you! I look the diffrent of code "Assign" and "SetPngImage". And "SetPngImage" have call "Changed" function. I want to use Assign for "TPngImageCollectionItem" only becouse they have already copy "Name" and "Background" and don't expected then can't use for this situation.